# How do I install the @Release version of my Azure Artifact Nuget?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

In my NuGet feed, I have promoted my current package to @Release (a View, not a Tag). After I publish a new version, how do I get Install-Module to give me the @Release version, not the latest published? I tried something like:

```
Find-Module -Name MyAwesomeMod -RequiredVersion @Release
```

This still listed the last published, which isn't yet in the @Release view.

Answer (score 1):

Views are effectively a virtual *feed* that provides a filtered subset of their base feed. To use it you would add @Release after the name of the feed in the feed URL, e.g. https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Contoso/LitWare/_packaging/LitWarePackages@Release/nuget/v2/